# Why setUserId method not work in entity symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Why my methid setUserId not work? 
It's my Post entity:

```
<?php
// src/Acme/UserBundle/Entity/User.php

namespace Acme\PostBundle\Entity;


use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="posts")
 */
class Post
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;
    /**
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer",  nullable=false)
     */
    public $user_id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Acme\PostBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="posts")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $user;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Введите текст")
     * )
     */
    protected $text;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $address;
    /**
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    protected $date;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set user_id
     *
     * @param integer $userId
     * @return Post
     */
    public function setUserId($userId)
    {
        $this->user_id = $userId;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get user_id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getUserId()
    {
        return $this->user_id;
    }

    public function getText()
    {
        return $this->text;
    }

    public function __construct() {
        $this->date = new \DateTime();
    }
    //...

}
```

And my User entity:

```
<?php
// src/Acme/UserBundle/Entity/User.php

namespace Acme\PostBundle\Entity;


use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 */
class User
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
    */
    protected $id;
    /**
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $path;

    /**
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $username;
    /**
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Acme\PostBundle\Entity\Post", mappedBy="users")
    */
    protected $posts;

    public function __construct() {

        $this->posts = new ArrayCollection();

    }


}
```

I'm saving in the database via my controller:

```
 public function createAction(Request $request)
    {
        $post = new Post();

        $form = $this->createFormBuilder($post)
                     ->add('text')
                     ->add('address')
                     ->getForm();
        $post->setUserId($this->getUser()->getId());

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if($form->isValid()){
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($post);
            $em->flush();
        }

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('home'));    
    }
```

And i throw this error:

`Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'user_id' cannot be null`
Why? My `$this->getUser()->getId()` is not null, i tried `return new Response($this->getUser()->getId())` and get my id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need user_id field because you have user relation on field:

```
 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Acme\PostBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="posts")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $user;
/**
```

Look in you database, doctrine already created user_id for you.

Comment: i am don't understand why me do not need a user field in my entity? when i select this field returns me user object, look: http://pastebin.com/5nuBZiD6  if I use your version, you can do an insert into the database, but my select does not work out

Comment: Вecause to get user_id u will do $post->getUser()->getId()
And set user like $post->setUser(User interface $user); and not $post->setUserId(23);

Answer (score 0):

As the others stated its not possible to set `$userId` on its own if you have also defined an `$user` property as entity using the same database column.

Instead change your setters and keep everything else as it is:

```
class Post
{
    // ...

    /**
     * Set user_id
     *
     * @param integer $userId
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function setUserId($userId)
    {
        throw new \Exception('Post->userId can not be set directly');
    }

    /**
     * Set user
     *
     * @param User $user
     * @return Post
     */
    public function setUser($user)
    {
        $this->user    = $user;
        $this->user_id = $user->getId();

        return $this;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Now the `$userId` is automatically updated when you use `setUser(...)`. 
Throwing an exception in `setUserId` helps you preventing bugs in your code. Of course you could also just delete the setter, but it then would be recreated everytime you run another `doctrine:generate:entities` for your post entity.